# Xamarin Android BottomNavigation Bar can't work.Please Help me

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, bottomnavigationview

I was run the program it's was break mode.What wrong in my code Help me please.

UI only is fine but the program is break mode after add NavigationItemSelected event.

```
 private void BottomNavigation_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        //LoadFragment(e.Item.ItemId);
    }



void LoadFragment(int id)
    {
        Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (id)
        {
            case Resource.Id.menu_Meeting:
                fragment = MeetingFragment.NewInstance();
                break;
            case Resource.Id.menu_Project:
                fragment = ProjectFragment.NewInstance();
                break;
            case Resource.Id.menu_Account:
                fragment = AccountFragment.NewInstance();
                break;
        }
        if (fragment == null)
            return;

        SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
           .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment)
           .Commit();
    }
```

[Here Break Mode Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCzKx.jpg)
Please Help me!

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem on our side? Could you please a basic demo here so that we can test on our side?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WCsTicQaBRsypDvTLUie1FyLmbpLIPYr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT can you check my project please ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.You can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I achieved this function.

You can refer to the following code:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

    private SupportFragment mCurrentFragment;
    private MeetingFragment mFragment1;
    private ProjectFragment mFragment2;
    private AccountFragment mFragment3;
    private Stack<SupportFragment> mStackFragment;
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        bottomNavigation = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);

        bottomNavigation.NavigationItemSelected += (s, e) =>
        {
            Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (e.Item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.menu_Meeting:
                    fragment = new MeetingFragment();
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.menu_Project:
                    fragment = new ProjectFragment();
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.menu_Account:
                    fragment = new AccountFragment();
                    break;
            }
            SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
            .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment)
            .Commit();

            return;
        };

        mFragment1 = new MeetingFragment();
        mFragment2 = new ProjectFragment();
        mFragment3 = new AccountFragment();

        mStackFragment = new Stack<SupportFragment>();

        var trans = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        trans.Add(Resource.Id.content_frame, mFragment3, "Fragment3");//NOT bottom_navigation, it must be the container
        trans.Hide(mFragment3);
        trans.Add(Resource.Id.content_frame, mFragment2, "Fragment2");
        trans.Hide(mFragment2);
        trans.Add(Resource.Id.content_frame, mFragment1, "Fragment1");
        trans.Commit();

        mCurrentFragment = mFragment1;

    }
}
```